# Maximum call stack size exceeded with jQuery promise()

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise

I'm trying to apply a simple form validation in jQuery. If a form field is empty, add a class `error`. If any of the fields are empty, don't submit. I have the following:

```
$('#contact-form').submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var formValid = true;
    $('input.required, textarea.required, select.required').each(function() {
        if($(this).val() === '') {
            formValid = false;
            $(this).addClass('error');
        } else {
            $(this).removeClass('error');
        }
    }).promise().done(function() {
        if(formValid) {
            $('#contact-form').submit();
        }
    });
});
```

Howerver when the code hits the line to submit the form, I am seeing a JavaScript error:

**Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded**

Comment: I am suspecting it is because you are creating a promise on each of the field. Anyway, what's the purpose of having promise? I don't see asynchronous operations in the code.

Comment: The promise tells me when the `.each()` is finished.

Comment: @Justin: No, `.each()` is a *synchronous* function. It is finished when you reach the next line of code. You don't need and shouldn't use a promise for this. (More details in the answer below.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how your code would run if the form is valid:

1. on submit, prevent default action
2. check fields
3. if they are valid, form.submit - which causes submit event, goto step 1

endless recursion

it's very simple because there's no asynchronous code in the handler

```
$('#contact-form').submit(function(event) {
    var formValid = true;
    $('input.required, textarea.required, select.required').each(function() {
        if($(this).val() === '') {
            formValid = false;
            $(this).addClass('error');
        } else {
            $(this).removeClass('error');
        }
    });
    if (!formValid) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Comment: Ahh this is the problem. So how do I bind on `.submit()` and then be able to `submit()` later without re-entering the binding?

Comment: @WillianValhakis answer - though I don't like his return false instead of `preventDefault()` - that part is wrong

Comment: This is close, but requires clicking the form submit button twice. The first click does not submit the form.

Comment: hmmm, it's like the event handler isn't removed before submit is called - I hate jQuery internals - edited to use a `setTimeout` - always looks like a hack using that, but ...

Comment: Adding `setTimeout()` around `form.submit()` did not work. Still have to click twice. Lol this is absurd. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

How many fields do you have to validate, and why promise associated to each of them? try after checking all fields

```
if(formValid) {
            $('#contact-form').submit();
        }
else return false
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#contact-form').submit(function(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   var formValid = true;
   $('input.required, textarea.required, select.required').each(function() {
      if($(this).val() === '') {
         formValid = false;
         $(this).addClass('error');
      } else {
         $(this).removeClass('error');
      }
   }).promise().done(function() {
      if(formValid) {
         $("#contact-form").off('submit').submit();
      } 
   });
   return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First, `.promise().done(...)` can be purged. As has been said, nothing asynchronous is going on.

That aside, the actual issue is most likely the repeated re-invocation of the submit handler.

Try a POJS (as opposed to jQuery) form submission :

```
if(formValid) {
    this.submit();
}
```

Comment: the submit handler would still be called regardless of how the submit is invoked

Comment: Well, I learned something! I genuinely thought you were wrong :p

Comment: Since the beginning of time, browsers have behaved this way. Although the behaviour is still not in the W3C recommendation. I have yet to encounter a browser that does not comply.